# Change given code to match the time complexity O(n*log(n))

Tags: c, time, time-complexity

the current time complexity is θ(n<sup>2</sup>.log(n))
and I need to change the check in the For loop so the time complexity would be: θ(n.log(n)). A suggested solution is `i*i<n`, but I can't understand why.

```
int f2(int n)
{
     int x, y, z=0, i;
     for (x=n, i=0; i<n; i++, x*=n)
     {
          y=x;
          while (y>1)
              y/=3;
          z+=y;
     }
     return z;
 }
```

Comment: I feel there is a strikingly simple solution using the divisiability of n by 3. That would be O(0)+1.

Comment: @David You can use http://latex2png.com/ to convert it to an image and post it. (or just write `O(n*log(n))`)

Comment: `x` here will go up to a value of `pow(n,n+1)`. So you will likely overflow an `int` variable when `n` is 9 or more, making the complexity analysis mostly useless.

Comment: The question is about complexity, it's not about whether the code would compile or not.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the reason why the solution of the check condition is `i*i<n`.
The time complexity of the current code is the sums of the following logs:
`log(n)+log(n^2)+log(n^3)+...+log(n^n) = log(n)*(1+2+3+...+n)=` θ(n<sup>2</sup>.log(n)).
There for if I change the sum formula so the sum goes up to `sqrt(n)`, the result would be `((sqrt(n))^2 = n)`. and I will get the required time complexity:  θ(n*log(n).
and the code would be:

```
int f2(int n)
{
     int x, y, z=0, i;
     for (x=n, i=0; i*i<n; i++, x*=n)
     {
          y=x;
          while (y>1)
              y/=3;
          z+=y;
     }
     return z;
 }
```

Comment: But now you're computing a different value... When people talk about improving time complexity they generally want a function that computes the same thing but faster.

Comment: The return value is still the same, it is stupid question because I could just abandon the for loop at all and immediately return `z`, but they wanted us to change the condition, using `i`, to that required time complexity.

Comment: No, the return value is not the same. You add less values into `z` now.

Comment: After `while (y>1)` loop, I get that `y == 0` therefore it doesn't matter how many zeros I'm adding to Z

Comment: After that loop, `y` can be either 0 or 1. It would be easy to test and see that the two functions give different results.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't notice that. Still, this is the formal solution is `i*i<n` I'll check that with the Course responsible